# System Repair Disc vs Windows 10 on USB Stick

Tags: windows-10, bootable-media, system-recovery, system-repair-disc

Windows 10 Home.

I already have the Windows 10 installation image on a USB stick.

Is there any benefit for me to create a "System repair disc"?

Or can I accomplish the same thing (fixing unbootable Windows) with the USB stick?

Comment: Windows disc: Only command prompt. System repair disc: many extra GUI tools.